# How to enable OpenMP in CLion on MacBook

Tags: ios, cmake, openmp

[This is my CMakeList.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA0pu.png)
I also changed compiler to gcc-13:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kaFk.png)

I run it but have problem with architecture arm64:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4xWf.png)

I tried change compilers and different CMakeList.txt.

Comment: Please, post the code and the error message as a **text**. Images of text are discouraged on Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors